# Flutter getting data from database using a streambuilder problem

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

I was trying to get the data from database using a streambuilder. I followed a old tutorial and now it says:

> Error: The argument type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' because 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>?' is nullable and 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>'

The code is as follows:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
             stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').snapshots(),
             builder: (context, snapshot){
               if(!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
               else {
                 return Expanded(
                 child: _buildList(snapshot.data),
               );
               }
             }
             ),
```

Comment: Try just adding "?" in front of QuerySnapshot.
So convert `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>` to `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot?>`

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshots()` method will always return a `QuerySnapshot`, so you can just do:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').snapshots()!
                                                      // add this
```

Comment: I tried doing so but there is a error which says, "The '!' will have no effect because the receiver can't be null. (Documentation)  Try removing the '!' operator."

Comment: Thanks you so much for your recommendation. I finally found the error part and corrected. The error was actually a simple error where i had mistaken the spelling of the collection.